# html table value swapping

Tags: javascript, html

I have two tables created in `html`.. 
How could I move rows from one table to another table by choosing row via checkbox? 
Can anyone give me a sample JS to do this. Thanks

Comment: can you give your code here so we can also answer you in terms of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function moveIt() {
  $('#table-1 input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function() {
    var tr = $(this).parents('tr').get(0);
    $('#table-2').append($(tr));
  });
}
</script>

<table border="1" id="table-1">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>First</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>Second</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>Third</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table border="1" id="table-2">
</table>

<input type="button" onclick="moveIt()" value="move selected lines from table-1 to table-2" />
```

Don't forget to include jQuery.

Comment: hi just one thing Mr Muhammad, what if I would like to add all rows in table-1 without checking all checked checkbox.. It's like button Select All?

Comment: Then you need to change $('#table-1 input[type=checkbox]:checked') to $('#table-1 input[type=checkbox]'), so it will match all checkboxes, not only checked checkboxes only

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [jQuery](http://jquery.com). Something like this should do the job.

```
$(function() {
    // Bind button
    $('#moveRows').click(moveSelectedRows);
    // Select All-button
    $('#selectAll').click(function() {
        $('#table1 input[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked", true);
    });
});

function moveSelectedRows() {
    $('#table1 input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
        // Remove from #table1 and append to #table2
        $('#table2').append($(this).closest('tr').remove());
        // Remove the checkbox itself
        $(this).remove();
    });
}
```

HTML

```
<a href="#" id="selectAll">Select All</a>

<table id="table1">
    <tr>
        <td>Foo1 <input type="checkbox" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Bar2 <input type="checkbox" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table id="table2">
    <tr>
        <th>Selected rows</th>
    </tr>
</table>

<a id="moveRows" href="#">Move rows</a>
```

Comment: where I will put the event? or how could I call the jQuery function?

Comment: @Mark The function calls itself when you click the button. I'll edit for more clarity.

Comment: thanks for it, it's working.. Just still one thing I want to know. How could I transfer all data on table1 into table2 without validating all checked checkbox (e.g Select All)?

Comment: @Mark I have added a function for selecting all checkboxes in table1. If you also want to move them with this button, add `moveSelectedRows()` to the `$('#selectAll').click()` event

Answer (score 0):

THis is simplest way to copy the content of one tr to another tr

[see this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kunalvashist/z2aL7/)

The key point is to get the innerHTML and move it to desired part